# Use WCF without adding its reference

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, wcf, assembly-references

I'm working with SharePoint 2010 and using a WCF service in my project. Due to some reasons some class names in my WCF were changed, that caused me to remove and add the service reference and recompile the SharePoint project again. I'm thinking if it's possible some how that I can have service functionality in my SharePoint project without adding direct reference to the service. I got to know on some blogs that if I create a another WCF client and add reference to this project and depend on my service's interface. I'm not sure how to do this. If you have any clue on this please share.

Answer (score 0):

It's always possible to [Consuming an On-Premise WCF Service from SharePoint 2010 using JQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/spazuretrainingcourse_onpremwcffromsponpremusingjquery.aspx):

> Consuming on-premise WCF services from SharePoint is easily accomplished via any Web Part that can run HTML, JavaScript and JQuery. This includes the HTML form Web Part, any custom developed Visual Web Part and Silverlight Web Parts (that uses the HTML DOM Bridge). The chief mechanism which allows SharePoint to communicate with back-end systems protected by firewalls is the Azure AppFabric Service bus.

Use the tutorial and you're well on your way to use WCF from SharePoint.

Comment: I am looking something like Dependency Injection, unity framework and Inversion of Control.

Comment: @V.B Do you mean something like the framework from Codeplex? [Dependency Injection and Windows Communication Foundation](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/251265/Dependency-Injection-and-Windows-Communication-Fou)

Comment: Yes something like this. Idea is I want to create a wcf client and and create my own class there which implements the same interface that wcf has and use my own class to call the service methods. I think this makes my independent of WCF if any class name changes but the interface doesn't.

Comment: @V.B That's the whole point of using WCF. Personally I'd like to build my WCF consumer from .NET only to make the solution maintainable. If I use a custom framework, I'm somewhat blinded by the black box of framework. But that's me.